# Call function on app termination in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

How can I call a function that is within an SKScene class when my app is terminated by the user?

I need to modify a value and save it to NSUserDefauts when the app is terminated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can register to receive a notification when your app is about to terminate. To do this, add an observer to the default notification center by

***Swift 5:***

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(saveData), name: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification, object: nil)
```

**Swift 3/4:**

```
// Add this to didMoveToView in your SKScene subclass
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(saveData), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)
```

Add the following method to your `SKScene` subclass. The method will be called before the app terminates. It must be "exposed" to Objective-C by adding `@objc` so the notifier can use `#selector()`.

```
@objc func saveData(notification:NSNotification) {
    // Save your data here
    print("Saving data...")
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 3 and 4 you have something like that:
in your viewDidLoad

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(toDoSomething), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillTerminate, object: nil)
```

and than you have that method to be called

```
 func suspending () {
        print("toDoSomething...")
}
```

Comment: `name: UIApplication.willTerminateNotification` in Swift 5

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods in [UIAppDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/index.html) that will help you. Take a look at `applicationWillTerminate(_:)` and `applicationWillResignActive(_:)`. From there you see what state your app is in and do perform the appropriate actions.

Comment: applicationWillTerminate mostly dont be called.